# How to reload tableView with another tableView selected row values?

Tags: ios, objective-c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeMHV.png)I have created 4 UITableView in a single ViewController. 
Ex. (Main UITableView, Project UITableView, Issue UITableView, Activity UITableView). 
Main UITableView has 10 rows with a button in every row(project, issue, activity). When click button in Project UITableView will show and select anyone values in Main UITableView and Project button show on selected values.

Comment: please add some code by which you are trying

Comment: create four delegate class for each table.

Comment: Also show us some screenshots or sketches to help us understand what exactly you are trying to do, it's not really clear at all.

Comment: Here is the sample screenshot http://i.stack.imgur.com/LeMHV.png. please take a look. please help me any sample code . I have more than week spent of times.

Answer (score 0):

Use delegate

in table1.h

```
@protocol Table1Delegate;

@interface Table1ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id < Table1Delegate > delegate;

@end

@protocol Table1Delegate
@required

@optional
    -(void) table1ViewControllerDidSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end


@interface table1ViewController : UITableViewController 

@property (nonatomic, weak) id < Table1Delegate > delegate;
@end
```

in table1.m file

in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//do what you do an then call
 [self.delegate table1ViewControllerDidSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];

}
```

in table2.h

```
#import table1.h
#import "fa13ChooseListTableViewController.h"

@interface fa13ClubTableViewController : UITableViewController<MenuViewControllerDelegate>
@end
```

in table2.m
in viewDidLoad you need to getTable1 controller instance and set to its delegate property table2 instance (self)
then implement table1ViewControllerDidSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method

```
-(void) table1ViewControllerDidSelectRowAtIndexPath:(UICollectionViewController *)controller {
//do what you need to do with data from table1

}
```

indexPath was used as an example, you can path to delegate any object you want.

Comment: UITableView single page viewcontroller. this code will be a different class. I think single class only. how to main UITableView reload.

Comment: it is even easier:
`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(tableView == self.table1) {
//do what you want in table2
}
}`

Comment: Are you see this my sample image. its working fine every UITableView selected values. but didn't main UITableView reload. please help me. sample code

Comment: could you please send ur mail address I will send my project code.

Comment: Upload code to some cloud service and post link to it right there.

Comment: now it's working fine. below is my code.[tableview beginupdates];
[tableview reloadAtIndexpaths:[tableview indexpathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tableview reloadData];. here is another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917268/how-to-solve-this-error-this-class-is-not-key-value-codeing-compliant-for-the-k/34917347#34917347