# How to solve this error "this class is not key value coding compliant for the key"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created `UITableView` and in `UITableview` every row have more than one `UITextField`. How to get each `UITextField` values. Below is my sample code.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
    int  j= 285;        
            for (int i=0; i<7; i++) { 
    NSString *txtIndvalue =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Index%d",i];           
                UITextField *txtvalue =  [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(j,5.0f,25.0f,20.0f)];
                [txtvalue setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];
    [txtvalue setTag:indexpath.row]
    [txtvalue setvalue:txtIndvalue forkey:@"test"]
                [cell addSubview:txtvalue];
                j = j + 35;
            }
    }

error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownkeyException' ,reason :'[<UItextField .>' setValue:forUndefindekey:] this class is not key value codeing compliant for the key. Please help me.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[txtvalue setvalue:txtIndvalue forkey:@"test"]
```

This line causing the crash. `setValueForKey` is not a property/method of `UITextField`. If you want to set text on textfield , you should use

```
txt value.text = @"some text".
```

Comment: [txtvalue setvalue:txtIndvalue forkey:@"test"] is a method/ property of UITextField. void setvalue:(id) forkey:(NSString *). could you please check again. how to each textbox every row values.

Comment: Please check the answer added by @BEN below. He is setting by using KVC/KVO pattern.

Comment: @Baskar do you want to display row number in text field. If that is concern , txt value.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indepath.row];

Comment: No, every row textbox enter value get and which textbox values in rows.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use KVC for UITextField try this :

```
[txtvalue setvalue:txtIndvalue forkey:@"text"];
```

**EDIT**

try this :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
int  j= 285;        
        for (int i=0; i<7; i++) { 
NSString *txtIndvalue =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Index%d",i];           
            UITextField *txtvalue =  [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(j,5.0f,25.0f,20.0f)];
            [txtvalue setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];
[txtvalue setTag:indexpath.row];
[txtvalue setvalue:txtIndvalue forkey:@"text"];
            [cell addSubview:txtvalue];
            j = j + 35;
        }
}
```

Comment: any sample code. with update my code. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using for KVC:

Instead of using `[txtvalue setvalue:txtIndvalue forkey:@"text"];` use `[txtIndvalue setValue:txtIndvalue forKeyPath:@"text"];`

**Updated code:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
int  j= 285;        
        for (int i=0; i<7; i++) { 
NSString *txtIndvalue =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Index%d",i];           
            UITextField *txtvalue =  [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(j,5.0f,25.0f,20.0f)];
            [txtvalue setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];
[txtvalue setTag:indexpath.row];
[txtvalue setvalue:txtIndvalue forKeyPath:@"text"];
            [cell addSubview:txtvalue];
            j = j + 35;
        }
}
```

**Print the value of KVC:**

```
NSLog(@"%@", [txtvalue valueForKey:@"text"];
```

Comment: how to get textbox enter values.